# Pre-1975 children's novel: alien befriends children, opposed aliens wipe their memories

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

I am looking for a children's science fiction book that I read in 1975.  I can only remember fragments of scenes from the book.

What I can remember:

1. Possibly warring alien factions.
2. The "good" alien befriends a group of school children and recruits their assistance.
3. The children accompany the "good" alien on an adventure, when they realize that they do not have any food with them, the alien gives them a pill that provides them with all the nutrition that they require, and also tastes like whatever food the child thinks about.
4. When caught by the "bad" alien(s) the children are shot with something (arrows?) that causes them to forget about the aliens entirely.  All of the children except the youngest in the group are affected by the memory wipe.  The youngest child then tries to restore the other children's memories and help the "good" alien.

Comment: This reads as if the good alien may not be good and the bad alien(s) may not be bad. Did you intend that and is that a given? Knowing that might help in answering the question.

Comment: No.  The "good" and "bad" designations are my feelings.  Sadly, I am working with a 40 year old memory, which is sketchy at best.  It could be that the "good" alien was on the run trying to clear its name and was being pursued by the alien authorities... The possibilities are endless.  And, my memory faulty.

Comment: Thanks to Richard, and Rand for correcting my blunders.

Comment: Reminded me of [My Teacher is an Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teacher_Is_an_Alien), but that was written in 1989.

Comment: @BryanDavis —Trust me, I absolutely understand about fraying memories. That one of the reasons I decided to participate here.

Comment: Do you remember anything about how the kids meet the alien?

Comment: @DCShannon Sadly, no.  I do remember that the "good" alien, just prior to it's capture, had the group of children surround the youngest/smallest member of the group to prevent that child from being shot with the memory erasing dart.

Comment: Were the darts golden?  This is tickling at my brain; I know I've read this, but I can't think of any clear details to add.